# Why does Windows Installer check the volume information of a shared drive when installing a file within the shared drive?

Tags: permissions, windows-installer

I'm running into an issue where one of my users is having trouble installing a Windows Installer file. The file is located on a shared drive that the user doesn't have complete access to, but the user does have access to the file itself. When the user tries to run the installer, we see the following issue in the log file:

```
MSI (s) (F4:14) [12:28:41:425]: Note: 1: 2303 2: 5 3: \\share\base\  
MSI (s) (F4:14) [12:28:41:425]: Note: 1: 2303 2: 5 3: \\share\base\  
MSI (s) (F4:14) [12:28:41:425]: Unable to create a temp copy of patch '\\share\base\installers\version\patches\patch.msp'. 
This update package could not be opened. Verify that the update package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer update package.  
C:\Windows\Installer\44987c.msi  
MSI (s) (F4:14) [12:28:41:425]: Note: 1: 1708
```

The first line seems to correspond with error 2303, which is "Error getting volume info." according to the MSDN documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372835(v=vs.85).aspx). Matching that up with a Proc Mon log yields that the Windows Installer service impersonating my user was denied read attributes access to the \\share\base directory. I believe fixing the issue is just a matter of providing read attributes permission to the user.

However, my question is why does Windows Installer need to access that directory to perform the installation? I would imagine that Windows Installer might get volume information about the local drives or the Windows drive, but I can't figure out why it tries to get extra information about the root-ish directory of the shared drive. It doesn't seem like the user should need the extra permissions to the read attributes in order to install the Windows Installer.

Thanks for your help,
Jake